# Cant add data to xml from list using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This code doesn't work for me and I can't understand why.

```cs
xmlDoc.Element("results").Add(
                new XElement("user",
                    new XAttribute("id", user.Id),
                    new XAttribute("facebookid", user.FacebookId),
                    new XAttribute("email", user.Email),
                    new XAttribute("totalpoints", totalpoints)
                    ).Add(
                            user.Answers.Select(value => new XElement("question",
                            new XAttribute("id", value.QuestionId),
                            new XAttribute("answer_id", value.AnswerId),
                            new XAttribute("points", value.Points)))
                          )
                  );
```

I'm trying to create this

```xml
<results>
  <user id="2323" facebookId="3254954795743957" email="david@gmail" totalPoints="">
    <question id="1" answer_id="3" points="0" />
    <question id="2" answer_id="1" points="1" />
  </user>
</results>
```

Comment: What is the result? Did you call "Save"? For attributes use `XAttribute` not `XElement`.

Comment: I haven't been able to get a result as apparently the syntax is wrong. I  just don't get why

Comment: If the syntax is wrong you can see an error in the Error List tool window. What is the error you see?

Comment: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Add(object)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1):

```
xmlDoc.Element("results").Add(
    new XElement("user",
        new XAttribute("id", user.Id),
        new XAttribute("facebookid", user.FacebookId),
        new XAttribute("email", user.Email),
        new XAttribute("totalpoints", totalpoints),
        user.Answers.Select(value => new XElement(
                "question",
                new XAttribute("id", value.QuestionId),
                new XAttribute("answer_id", value.AnswerId),
                new XAttribute("points", value.Points)
            ))
        )
    );
```

The problem was that the `Add` method returns `void` so you can't continue with another `Add` over the `void` result. Also, for attributes you need to use `XAttribute`, not `XElement`.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes more sense. Thank you!!